# R how to automatically adjust y axis when using basic plot with xlim

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to use base R (and would like to stick to it for this problem) to plot a specific portion of a dataset.

My example data looks like below:

```
x <- c(1:100)
y <- sort(runif(100, min=0, max=1000))
```

When I plot this with `plot(x,y, type='l')`, I get a plot with a y axis that shows 0 to 1000. However, when I plot only a specific `x`  range, my y axis still shows 0 to 1000. I would like to zoom in to reduce the y axis range.

For example,

```
plot(x,y, type='l', xlim=c(40,60))
plot(x,y, type='l', xlim=c(80,90))
```

both produces plots with a y axis that ranges `c(0,1000)`. But I'd like to zoom in so that the y axis range for the first plot is something like `c(300,700)` and that for the second plot is `c(700,1000)`. (`300`, `700` and `1000` are all arbitrary numbers just to illustrate the purpose to really zoom into the plot). Is there a way to do this without setting specific  `ylim`?

I'd like to avoid using `ylim` because I'm plotting and saving in a `for` loop and I can't write a `ylim` that is suitable for all plots. I've thought of doing something like `ylim = max(y)*1.5`, but again, since I'm cutting the `y` values off based on `xlim`, this doesn't help with zooming in whenever `xlim` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset the relevant data and plot that

```
lower = 40
upper = 60
ind = which(x >= lower & x <= upper)
plot(x[ind], y[ind], type = "l")
```